# XCode Global Breakpoints don't show stack trace

Tags: iphone, xcode, stack-trace, breakpoints

I set up global break points from locations libobjc.A.dylib and CoreFoundation.  I run my iphone app and it hits the exception.  XCode stops at the breakpoint but does not show any error in the log besides: 
Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - "-[NSException raise]" resolved

I click the "Continue" button on the console and I get the same indistinguishable error I received before I enabled the breakpoints.

How do I get the stack trace that setting up the global breakpoints is supposed to generate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

type `bt` or `backtrace` from the GDB console

Comment: how do you see line numbers as well?

Comment: short version: up and down are commands to move the stack frame (your window of debug :P ) up and down the stack you see with bt